# Assigning text to specific row

Tags: excel, rows, row-number

I wonder if there's a way in Excel to assign a text in cell to a row that would correspond to a number next to that cell. Let's say I have a long list of entries with numbers next to them and I need those entries to be in a row (of lets say column B) that is same as a number next to those entries and any space between them to be blank (so i can have 1,2,3,5,10,104,... and so on). How could I do this? is there a formula or like a macro that would accomplish this?

Comment: Assuming this list is in columns F (text) and G (numbers) then `=IFERROR(INDEX(F:G, MATCH(ROW(), G:G, 0), 1), "")` in `B1` and copy down.

Comment: It's quite unclear. What exactly would your data look like? Can you include some simple sample data and expected output.

Comment: worked seamlessly, thanks!

Comment: it looks like a1:1 b1:some text, a2:3 b2: some text... and output should be c1:text(from b1), c3:text(from b2)...

Comment: Either VLOOKUP or INDEX+MATCH can achieve that. Try google the the know how of these two methods.